# Conventions for R, G, B and A arrangement in RGBA byte buffers

Tags: image, image-processing

Are there any conventions when representing an image as an RGBA byte buffer? There are multiple ways to do so, for example

1. Grouped (4 pixel image, 16 byte array)

```
RGBA, RGBA, RGBA, RGBA
```

1. Separated (4 pixel image, 16 byte array)

```
RRRR, GGGG, BBBB, AAAA
```

Comment: Your first is sometimes called *"band-interleaved by pixel"*. Your second *"planar"*. There is also **BIL**, or *"band-interleaved by line"*.

Comment: @MarkSetchell can you post this as an answer?